# Understanding sample midterm test, multi class with println

Tags: java, class, this, public, void

Hey everyone I'm studying for a midterm exam and I'm studying the sample midterm from a previous semester, the answers are given but I'm trying to figure out how the answers came about. Question and answers below, I understand how he got "zero" but not the rest:

Write the 10-lines output of the program  Bird.java shown below.

```
interface Silly {
   public void narf();
   public void poit(Silly s);
}

public class Bird implements Silly {
public static void main(String args[]) {
     System.out.println("zero");
     Silly s = new SillyBird(1);
     Silly s2 = new Loony();
     s.poit(s2);
     s2.poit(s);
     System.out.println("zymurgy");
   }
   public Bird() {
     this(0);
     System.out.println("zircon");
   }
   public Bird(int i) {
     System.out.println("zanzibar");
   }
   public void narf() {
     System.out.println("zort");
   }
   public void poit(Silly s) {
      s.narf();
   }
}

class SillyBird extends Bird {
   public SillyBird() {
     System.out.println("duchess");
   }
   public SillyBird(int i) {
      super(i);
   }
   public void narf() {
      System.out.println("drum");
      super.narf();
   }
}

class Loony extends SillyBird {
   public Loony() {
      System.out.println("stupendous");
   }
   public void narf() {
     System.out.println("snark");
   }
}
```

His answers are: zero
zanzibar
zanzibar
zircon
duchess
stupendous
snark
drum
zort
zymurgy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
interface Silly {
   public void narf();
   public void poit(Silly s);
}

public class Bird implements Silly {
public static void main(String args[]) {
     System.out.println("zero");   // 1. zero
     Silly s = new SillyBird(1);   // 2. zanzibar
     Silly s2 = new Loony();       // 3. zanzibar zircon duchess stupendous
     s.poit(s2);                   // 4. snark
     s2.poit(s);                   // 5. drum zort
     System.out.println("zymurgy");// 6. zymurgy
   }
   public Bird() {
     this(0);
     System.out.println("zircon");
   }
   public Bird(int i) {
     System.out.println("zanzibar");
   }
   public void narf() {
     System.out.println("zort");
   }
   public void poit(Silly s) {
      s.narf();
   }
}

class SillyBird extends Bird {
   public SillyBird() {
     System.out.println("duchess");
   }
   public SillyBird(int i) {
      super(i);
   }
   public void narf() {
      System.out.println("drum");
      super.narf();
   }
}

class Loony extends SillyBird {
   public Loony() {
      System.out.println("stupendous");
   }
   public void narf() {
     System.out.println("snark");
   }
}
```

I hope this helps... I think the most important one to understand is number 3 where you have implicit super() calls.

Answer (score 1):

WHat you probably don't get is that whan a constructor doesn't explicitely invoke super(), then the compiler adds a `super()` call anyway, to the very beginning of the constructor. So,

```
public SillyBird() {
     System.out.println("duchess");
}
```

is equivalent to

```
public SillyBird() {
    super(); 
    System.out.println("duchess");
}
```

Add the `super()` calls at the very beginning of the constructors which don't have one, then follow the calls, and you'll find the answer. For example, the call to

```
Silly s2 = new Loony();
```

calls the `Loony` constructor, which calls super(). So the SillyBird no-arg constructor is called, which first calls super(). So the Bird no-arg constructor is called, which calls `this(0)`. SO the 1-arg constructor of Bird is called, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't understand how 'he got the rest' - you need to read a basic tutorial on objects, classes, and interfaces.  Start with the one provided by [Oracle](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html).  In a nutshell, the print statements occur in the same order the constructors and override methods are being executed.  For example, the second word 'zanzibar' is printed because the

```
public SillyBird(int i) {
    super(i);
}
```

constructor is invoked `Silly s = new SillyBird(1);`, which invokes:

```
public Bird(int i) {
    System.out.println("zanzibar");
}
```

via the `super(i)` invocation.

Now try to reason through how the second 'zanzibar' print occurs.